# Java 8 lambdas grouping reducing and mapping

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a `List` of the following `Transaction` class, using Java 8 lambdas, I want to obtain a `List` of `ResultantDTO`, one per account type.

```
public class Transaction {

    private final BigDecimal amount;
    private final String accountType;
    private final String accountNumber;

}

public class ResultantDTO {

    private final List<Transaction> transactionsForAccount;

    public ResultantDTO(List<Transaction> transactionsForAccount){
        this.transactionsForAccount = transactionsForAccount;
    }

}
```

So far, I use the following code to group the `List<Transaction>` by `accountType`.

```
Map<String, List<Transaction>> transactionsGroupedByAccountType = transactions
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getAccountType));
```

How do I return a `List<ResultantDTO>`, passing the List from each map key into the constructor, containing one `ResultantDTO` per `accountType`?

Comment: Can you show how you would do what you want without `Stream` operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in single stream operation:

```
public List<ResultantDTO> convert(List<Transaction> transactions) {
    return transactions.stream().collect(
            collectingAndThen(
                groupingBy(
                        Transaction::getAccountType,
                        collectingAndThen(toList(), ResultantDTO::new)),
                map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())));
}
```

Here `collectingAndThen` used twice: once for downstream `Collector` to convert lists to the `ResultantDTO` objects and once to convert the resulting map to list of its values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a:

```
static ResultantDTO from(List<Transaction> transactions) {...}
```

You could write:

```
Map<String, List<Transaction>> transactionsGroupedByAccountType = transactions
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getAccountType));

Map<String, ResultantDTO> result = transactionsGroupedByAccountType.entrySet().stream()
         .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> from(e.getValue)));
```

You may be able to do it in one stream but this is probably cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `toMap` collector:

```
Map<String, ResultantDTO> transactionsGroupedByAccountType = transactions
                .stream()
                .collect(toMap(Transaction::getAccountType,
                        t -> new ResultantDTO(t.getAmount(), 
                                              Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>(t.getAccountNumber(), t.getAmount()))
                                                    .collect(toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue))),
                        (dt1, dt2) -> new ResultantDTO(dt1.getSumOfAmountForAccountType().add(dt2.getSumOfAmountForAccountType()), 
                                                       Stream.of(dt1.getAccountNumberToSumOfAmountForAccountNumberMap(), dt2.getAccountNumberToSumOfAmountForAccountNumberMap())
                                                             .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                                                             .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))));
```

although its not very readable. Maybe you could add a constructor that takes a single `Transaction` as parameter and a merger in the `ResultantDTO` class:

```
 public ResultantDTO(Transaction t) {
     ///
 }

 static ResultantDTO merger(ResultantDTO r1, ResultantDTO r2) {
     ///
 }
```

and there it is more readable:

```
Map<String, ResultantDTO> transactionsGroupedByAccountType = transactions
                .stream()
                .collect(toMap(Transaction::getAccountType,
                               ResultantDTO::new,
                               ResultantDTO::merger));
```